# Canvas Comment/Document in Dart SDK

Tags: dart

Is it possible to have an explicit explanation of what the following code does rather than showing only a meaningless reference.

Please note this piece of code is taken from the dart:html package (html_dartium.dart) where defines the class CanvasRenderingContext2D.

```
/// @domName CanvasRenderingContext2D
class CanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasRenderingContext {
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.internal(): super.internal();


  /** @domName CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle */
  dynamic get fillStyle native "CanvasRenderingContext2D_fillStyle_Getter";

  ...
```

Comment: Hui, I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you be a little bit more explicit about what you want? I'm not sure what you mean by "real documents" and "dart html source codes." Please elaborate a bit and I'll try to help (or locate someone else who can). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Shalien, I've imporved my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: dart:html is mostly autogenerated from some WebKit definitions. Hence, it doesn't have really great documentation. The answer below mostly explains what "native" does. Other than that, you can refer to normal HTML5 documentation to learn more about the Canvas API.If you're satisfied with the answer below, please be sure to approve it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Shannon, you've given a nice answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fillStyle` `getter` uses `native` code. Hence the somewhat cryptic code there. To find out more about native code in Dart, I would recommend this article:

http://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/

Here's an excerpt:

```
The Dart library defines classes and top-level functions as usual, but declares that
some of these functions are implemented in native code, using the native keyword. The
native library is a shared library, written in C or C++, that contains the 
implementations of those functions.
```

Dart hasn't changed the `Canvas` api, so you can read about that api and get a good idea of what the code is doing. Here is a good place to start:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

If you have a more general complain about lack of explicit documentation (especially where `native` code is used), you can always file a bug.